# Refreshing a div every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

there is a particular value i called from the database into the div named #freq_count and i want to only refresh #freq_count every 30 seconds. i know of a refresh that calls a page into a div and refreshes but this time i'm looking for a code that can only refresh a div without calling any external pages. this tried this code, it worked but changed the whole look of the page, i dont know if i could get anyone one which works perfectly

```
$('#freq_count').load('count_freq.asp #freq_count');
```

Comment: That code *should* work. Can you provide some more details on how and when you execute it (showing more of the code might shed a light on the problem). Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: body {text-align:center; background-image: url('http://cdn3.crunchify.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Crunchify.bg_.300.png')}
 
 
  $(document).ready(function() {
   auto_refresh();
  });
  function auto_refresh(){
   var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
   $('#show').text('I am getting refreshed every 3 seconds..! Random Number ==> '+ randomnumber);
  }
  var refreshId = setInterval(auto_refresh, 1000);

Comment: what i mean is there is a div on my page called #freq_count which contains a value called from the table database and i want to refresh that div every 30 seconds